# The boiling point of carbon monoxide (CO) at 1 Torr

Tags: thermodynamics

The boiling point of carbon monoxide (CO) at one atmosphere (760 Torr) is -191.5 degrees Centigrade or 81.65 degrees Kelvin. What is its boiling point at 1 Torr ? Or perhaps there is no liquid phase at 1 Torr ??

Comment: Try to find a detailed phase diagram for CO or N2, their properties are similar. The triple points are about 65K ; the vapor pressure of the solid falls drastically below the triple point.

Comment: Jim, That's a good Idea. There is probably no liquid phase at one Torr anyway. Stan

Comment: Google vapor pressure of carbon monoxide.